# Authentication to Office365 on iOS

Tags: ios, sharepoint-2013, basic-authentication, office365, adfs

After 2 weeks of searching with no luck, I ended up writing this question:
Can you help me how to authenticate into Office365 on iOS? My goal is to list all rooms in my company included in outlook.

Is connecting to Sharepoint a solution for this? If it is so, how should it be performed and to which link shall be send credentials?
Is basic authentication enough to access those services?
I have tried doing authentication to EWS, but at the end of the day it turn out wrong.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: you want to login to exchange online or SharePoint online? Or just the office365 addmin portal?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be the OWA app for iOS.  If you are looking to access all of the room mailboxes from a single location.  You can manage multiple accounts from the OWA app if that is what you are after.  Aside from the the Office Mobile app has the other collaboration pieces that come along with certain licenses in Office 365.